# DateTime - check for yesterdays data (SQLCe)

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-ce

In my app, I work with dates (stored as DateTime) the way I use only the date part.
For Invoices issued today, I use the following (works fine):

```
WHERE DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, IssuedOn))=DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()))";
```

But what about invoices issued yesterday - day before current date? I tried to subtract these and check if the results i 1 but that does not work.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need because you are using sql-server 2005 or earlier:

```
WHERE 
IssuedOn >= DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 1, GETDATE()))
and IssuedOn < DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()))
```

It can be shortened like this instead:

```
WHERE 
IssuedOn >= DATEDIFF(D, 1, GETDATE())
and IssuedOn < DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE())
```

Remember to tag version and RDBMS

Comment: As I mentioned, it is SQL Ce.

Answer (score 0):

If you want indexes to have a chance to be used, do not apply any function on the columns. Your condition (for today) would be written as:

```
WHERE IssuedOn >= DATEADD(day, 0 + DATEDIFF(day, '20000101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '20000101')
  AND IssuedOn <  DATEADD(day, 1 + DATEDIFF(day, '20000101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '20000101')
```

and for yesterday:

```
WHERE IssuedOn >= DATEADD(day, -1 + DATEDIFF(day, '20000101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '20000101')
  AND IssuedOn <  DATEADD(day,  0 + DATEDIFF(day, '20000101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '20000101')
```

Comment: Says that this is not supported in SQLCE.

Comment: Now it says that Date is not known type.

Comment: Ah, the `DATE` datatype is not available. I haven't used CE, can you test the latest revision?